# Как получить currentUser во Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Всем привет. Подскажите. Через middleware хочу посмотреть currentUser из Firebase. Пока только посмотреть, далее это буду использовать для защиты роутов.
Проблема в том, что user всегда null. Хотя я залогинен.
Как вариант, может быть глупость скажу и я не прав, но это из-за того, что middleware впереди планеты всей грузится и еще не получает состояние currentUser. А тогда как быть? Или другая может причина?

Так как еще использую Vuex, пытался делать проверку по геттеру из store. Но по факту все то же самое...
Для прикола через таймаут пробовал - тоже безрезультатно...

Также пробовал через событие это сделать - результат такой же. Через промисы вообще страница бесконечно грузится. Может я вообще не то делаю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так через промисы сработало, не? Он же по кругу на главную редиректит. А вообще firebase должен быть доступен сразу, может вы не так его прикрутили?

Comment: Не, промисы тоже не сработали. Я туда просто консоль вывел. И все, просто значок загрузки крутится. Плюс даже если редирект. Я размещал мидлвар только на одной странице. На главной он не должен отрабатывать... Опять же firebase из коробки идет в nuxt, просто импортнул... Но, конечно же, где-то я косячу в любом случае, иначе бы работало, мне кажется

Comment: как еще вариант - у вас firebase новый экземляр, а нужен из аппа

Comment: Не подскажете, как это можно проверить? Я еще немного нуб в этом вопросе

Comment: Я с firebase не работал, но смысл в том, что вам нужен тот экземпляр, который подключени ко vue, `this.firebase.auth()...` (незнаю будет ли доступен в роутере)